# Geometry-Is this a correct question?

Tags: geometry

[image]

ABis parallel to CD.The values of the angles are a,3x,2x and z as shown in the figure.Also,2x+z=100 degrees.Now it is required to find the value of angle a.I tried hard but could not solve it.I think some data is missing.Is is so?Or can it be solved?Please help.

Comment: Note that from your drawing, 2x+z can't be 100

Comment: @EmmadKareem-Drawing is of course not to scale...

Comment: Which angle is $x$? The picture is unreadable. Improve it.

Comment: I guess there is no x angle. There is an angle of value 2x only,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to determine $a$. So long as $3x < 80$, you can draw a triangle where $x$ is anything you want, $z$ is $100-2x$ and $a=80 - 3x$.